# Applying style to definition lists with html/css

Tags: css

I am creating a personal webpage and using a definition list for my basic information. I would like to enlarge the font of the individual list headers. For example;

```
<dt>Current Place of Residence:</dt>
<dd>Ann Arbor, Michigan</dd>
```

I would like to apply style JUST to the text encapsulated by the `<dt></dt>` tags. I am using a linked external CSS style sheet for my page. 
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

um, maybe I don't see your real problem, but isn't

```
dt { font-size:130%; /* … */ }
```

enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
dt {
 font-size: whatever;
 }
```

Definition list items can be styled just like anything else.